# Why did Pierce state his full name in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

After coming to know that one of the victims from the Night Owl murders happened to be
Lefferts in *L.A Confidential* (1997), Bud White recollected having seen Lefferts alongside Pierce on Christmas night.
This hunch led him to Pierce's residence which he located by tracing the address through
Nick's liquor store. Following this, Bud questioned Pierce about his potential
involvement in the heinous Night Owl murders:

> Pierce: Lynn Bracken is my Veronica Lake. I use girls that look like
> movie stars. Sometimes  I employ a plastic surgeon. When the work had
> been done, that's when you saw us.
>
> Bud White: That's why her mother couldn't ID her. Jesus fucking
> Christ.
>
> Pierce: No, Mr. White, **Pierce Morehouse Patchett**. I sense you're
> on your best behavior, but that's all I'm gonna tell you.

Why did Pierce state his full name in this scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be in direct response to the previous speaker referring to ['Jesus *something* Christ'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_H._Christ) as the reason why this young lady is unrecognisable.

There's a slight emphasis in the spoken version. Patchett points out that it wasn't "Jesus *fucking* Christ" what did it, but rather "Pierce *Morehouse* Patchett", evidently a man of similar godlike skills.